# Intermittent problem saving to MOSS 2007 from office 07 applications

Tags: 2007, document-library, my-site

We have an issue which is causing us a massive headache whereby teachers are complaining that students work hasn't been saving?

We use MOSS 2007 and each student has a mysite and they save to this as their local area (an N:\ drive is mapped to their mysite on logon)

The problem that is being reported is that a student will open a document (usually office) and will ammend an existing file. Then will save the work, log off etc....

When they then come back to work on the document which can be weeks later, they find that the work they had done, hadn't saved back although no errors were reported?

We are told this is a common occurance but erratic to which student/machine that it happens on.

We ourselves haven't yet been able to recreate the problem and other members of staff also save to sharepoint haven't seen the same problems?

To be honest we don't know where to begin with this one as we have nothing (as in errors) to go on.

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Any news on that topic, Matt?

Answer (score 1):

Without being too sure about it, it sounds like a user error. Maybe the students log out immediately after they saved the document. If many users do that at the same time or the documents are quite big, the log out will interrupt the saving process.

I suggest students check if the file is saved before closing office. If they cant find it in SharePoint, it should be possible to figure out where the file has been saved to (just click 'save as' to get the last saving location.)

Perhaps the 'open recent documents' menu in office can help as well. There might be a link to that missing document -just in case they choose the wrong sharePoint library...